# How to create this (see image below) type of visual from a table with relevent rows and columns in power bi?

Tags: powerbi

So, I am working on a project and the professor is bent on having a visual like the one attached. If you do not know what is written in image, I have an excel spreadsheet with following values -

Patashpur - 82%

Bhagwanpur - 84%

Kanthi - 84%  and so on.

I have to show this in
[image: this form]
(array of cards). How can I do this?
I have tried visualizing it as multi-row card, but the professor is not happy with it.

Comment: All these values (patashpur,bhawanpur etc) are coming from single column or you have seperate measure for each? It would helpful if you can share some sample data

Comment: You have to create one card per metric, there is no array of cards. You can group them together once you have created them

Comment: @Sam_Shri I have separate measure for each

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate card visual for your each value you want to show.

Additional to that enable **title** option from card visual property and add your title over there
[image]

Turn off the category option for your card to hide your measure name and enable shadow for looking more similar to your final output

[image]

[image]

Below would be your final output

[image]